# fopen ordering in C affecting it strangely

Tags: c, fopen

I have this code:

```
FILE *setup=fopen(strcat(cwd,"setup.txt"),"r");//navigates up to setup file

...//(doing stuff with setup)

fclose(setup);

FILE *paths=fopen(strcat(cwd,"stuff.txt"),"r");

char buff2[1024];

fgets(buff2,200,paths);


char thing[1024];

strcpy(thing,buff2);

printf(thing);

fclose(paths);
```

but it executes differently based on if I do code with setup or the code with paths first - only the first one works properly, the second just creates gibberish whenever fgets is called. fclose returns 0 as it should. The specific way I look at the second file doesn't seem to affect it. What's happening here?

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Check if `fopen()`s are successiful. [`strcat()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) will modify the contents of `cwd`. Did you initialize `cwd` properly before each `strcat()`? Also note that `printf(thing);` is dangerous because `thing` may contain `%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `strcat()`!

```
FILE *setup=fopen(strcat(cwd,"setup.txt"),"r");//navigates up to setup file
// cwd now has "...setup.txt"

FILE *paths=fopen(strcat(cwd,"stuff.txt"),"r");
// cwd now has "...setup.txtstuff.txt"
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'm new to C and keep forgetting how everything affects its inputs in weird ways

Comment: No, it is not weird. It's all documented.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat()` modifies `cwd`.

So if `cwd` originally contains `"/home/username/"`, the first call changes it to `"/home/username/setup.txt"`.

The second call appends to that, so it tries to open `"/home/username/setup.txtstuff.txt"`. This filename almost certainly doesn't exist, but you aren't checking for an error.

And if that filename is longer than the space allocated to `cwd`, you'll get a buffer overflow and undefined behavior.

Use a different variable to hold the filename to open.

```
char filename[MAXLENGTH];

sprintf(filename, "%s%s", cwd, "setup.txt");
FILE *setup = fopen(filename, "r");
...
fclose(setup);

sprintf(filename, "%s%s", cwd, "stuff.txt");
FILE *paths = fopen(filename, "r");
...
fclose(paths);
```